# Как установить whl-пакет не из PyPI, а зависимости из PyPI?

Tags: python, pip

У меня есть жутко секретный whl-пакетик `mysecretproject`, который, условно говоря, лежит в моём маленьком локалхостовом PyPI (каталог ли это, или pypiserver, или ещё что-то — неважно, могу использовать что угодно для решения задачи, хотя чем проще и изолированнее, тем лучше) и устанавливается оттуда. Предположим, что точная версия пакета мне неизвестна (его могу делать не я, например), и мне нужно установить просто последнюю доступную версию через pip.

Пакет настолько секретный, что даже имя пакета `mysecretproject` светить нигде не хочу <s>кроме этого вопроса</s>, поэтому на pypi.org нет и никогда не будет даже пустой заглушки.

Проблема в том, что pip в любом случае стучится одновременно и на локалхостовый PyPI, и на публичный `https://pypi.org/simple`, чтобы  попытаться достать последнюю версию whl-пакета оттуда.

Однако может случиться беда, и сверхсекретное название пакета случайно утечёт в интернетики в одном из моих случайных скриншотов.

Злоумышленник, налюбовавшись на скриншот, заливает на pypi.org `mysecretproject-99999.999.999`, в итоге мой pip ставит «более новую» версию пакета не с локалхоста, а из pypi.org — и всё, моя система скомпрометирована! (UPD 2021: [Я же говорил!](https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=54566)) (UPD 2023: Ну вот опять [я же говорил!](https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=58416)) Хочется как-то пофиксить эту проблему.

При этом прописать `--no-index` я тоже не могу, потому что зависимости нужно ставить как раз из pypi.org (предположим, что они белые и пушистые, да). Точное имя whl-файла я заранее тоже не знаю (версия пакета условно произвольная и заливается из другого моего локалхоста, например), поэтому просто скормить в pip прямой путь к whl-файлу я тоже не могу.

Как бы мне вывернуться так, чтобы pip ставил один-единственный мой пакет из локалхоста, а все его зависимости подтянул из pypi.org?

(Разработчики pip [уже говорили](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2090), что `--find-links` и аналоги занимаются оптимизацией, а не безопасностью, но безопасных аналогов мне найти так и не удалось)

Comment: Можно попробовать нарисовать костыль, который вычислит точное имя whl-пакета, сравнив доступные в каталоге версии по PEP 440, и скормит его в pip, но это как-то не выглядит адекватным

Comment: Есть временный костыль типа `pip install \`ls -t /path/to/wheels/mysecretproject-*.whl | head -n 1\``, но это тоже лютый неадекват

Comment: Решаемая задача допускает двойной запуск pip? Сначала установить зависимости модуля с PyPI, а затем следующим запуском установить целевой модуль из указанного репозитория `pip install --index-url http://localhost:8080/simple/ mysecretproject`

Comment: @ДмитрийПавлов получается, писать парсер зависимостей whl-пакета?)

Comment: Из сообщения я понял, что секретный модуль будете использовать не только вы. О какой секретности вообще тогда речь...Если же этот модуль вы используете лично, то может его и распространяемым модулем не стоит оформлять? Запакуйте его со всеми зависимостями каким-нибудь cx_Freeze или pyinstaller и запускайте на здоровье на любой машине (делают .exe или .sh из куска интерпретатора и всеми используемыми модулями, частично скрывают содержимое). Для этого способа есть статья на Хабре про использование хуков и дешифровщика при импорте модуля (скрывали исходники от заказчиков).

Comment: @ДмитрийПавлов зачем делать exe/sh, если существует whl? Не надо плодить сущностей, и к секретам это не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: Намекаете на то, что разработчик пакета не только не Вы (как было указано ранее), но и не должен знать о том, что вы пользуете модуль?)) Других объяснений такого танца с бубнами в голову не лезет...

Comment: @ДмитрийПавлов танцы с бубнами — это как раз exe/sh, а whl — это стандартный питоновый пакет, который я хочу всего лишь безопасно установить.

Answer (score 2):

> Проблема в том, что pip в любом случае стучится одновременно и на локалхостовый PyPI, и на публичный https://pypi.org/simple, чтобы попытаться достать последнюю версию whl-пакета оттуда.
>
> Злоумышленник, налюбовавшись на скриншот, заливает на pypi.org mysecretproject-99999.999.999, в итоге мой pip ставит пакет не с локалхоста, а из pypi.org — и всё, моя система скомпрометирована!

[`devpi`](https://www.devpi.net/) решает обе проблемы.

`devpi` может проксировать запросы на pypi.org: при запросе пакета `devpi` проверит, доступен ли пакет локально; если нет, то `devpi` перенаправит запрос на pypi.org. Чтобы сконфигурировать такое поведение, локальный индекс должен наследовать `root/pypi`. Если индекс не наследует `root/pypi`, установлены могут быть только пакеты, залитые непосредственно на индексе (индекс полностью изолирован).

Установка и настройка сервера подробно описана в документации; чтобы перманентно прописать установку с локального зеркала, открой `$HOME/.pip/pip.conf` и добавь:

```
[global]
index-url=http://127.0.0.1:9000/me/myindex/+simple
```

Поскольку используется `index-url`, `pip` будет использовать локальный репозитарий в качестве основного и единственного, игнорируя pypi.org. Дальше пакеты устанавливаются (или не устанавливаются) в зависимости от конфигурации индекса `devpi` (наследование `root/pypi`, описанное выше).

От ситуации, когда злоумышленник залил вредоносную копию `mysecretproject` на pypi.org, защищает опция индекса `mirror_whitelist`. Если имя пакета НЕ добавлено в `mirror_whitelist`, то `devpi` позволит установить только версии пакета, залитые на индексе, игнорируя любые версии, залитые на pypi.org. Имена пакетов никогда не добавляются в `mirror_whitelist` автоматически (это можно сделать только вручную), так что все залитые на локальных индексах пакеты изначально защищены от спуфинга.

Comment: Прикольная штука, но по-моему это чрезмерное усложнение инфраструктуры. А ограниченные возможности по контролю доступа и [невозможность слушать UNIX-сокет](https://github.com/devpi/devpi/issues/253) могут привести к другим потенциальным проблемам безопасности — например, когда на сервере несколько независимых пользователей (впрочем, то же самое относится и к pypiserver тоже)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1033317/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-python/1034393