# Пакеты в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть 2 `pypi-server`: один -- публичный, другой -- приватный. Как мне организовать `setup.py`, чтобы подягивать зависимости и оттуда, и оттуда?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как установить whl-пакет не из PyPI, а зависимости из PyPI?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/882086)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил проблему намного проще и, кажется, с меньшими костылями, чем указано выше, в ссылке. Я бы сказал, что ответ в комментарии не решает мою проблему.

Мне посоветовали несколько ссылок: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467463/default-server-in-multiple-server-configuration-of-distutils-in-pypirc), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087148/can-i-use-pip-instead-of-easy-install-for-python-setup-py-install-dependen). Но решил я проблему изящнее, на уровне питона, как мне кажется, с меньшими костылями:

```
try:
    from pip._internal import main as pipmain
except:
    print('your version of pip is deprecated')
    from pip import main as pipmain

# Some code here

setuptools.setup(**kwargs)
pipmain(['install', '-r', 'requirements.private'])
```

Иными словами, я явно вызываю `pip`. При этом, заранее я разделил на 2 части зависимости: `requirements.private`, `requirements` (публичный). Зависимости публичного репозитория будут установлены стандартными средствами `setuputool`. Приватные -- при помощи непосредственно `pip`. При этом, мы никак не завязываемся на систему (например, на alias, как это предлагается в одной из ссылок) и наш пакет полностью независим от окружения, что очень важно.